# Writing reg value to Local Machine in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Good Day all,

I am trying to create a registry entry for a piece of software i was asked to develop and have hit a wall. I have done multiple google searches and have not been able to get the changes to take. As of the last attempt my code looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RegistryKey Install = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", true);
            //string ToolKit = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
            string AtStart = "ValueName";
            string Value = @"C:\Program Files\SystemFolder\ToolFolder\Toolname.exe";

            if (Install.GetValue(AtStart, Value).ToString() == null)
            {
                Install.SetValue(AtStart, @"C:\Program Files\SystemFolder\ToolFolder\Toolname.exe", RegistryValueKind.String);
                //Registry.SetValue(ToolKit, AtStart, @"C:\Program Files\SystemFolder\ToolFolder\Toolname.exe");
            }
            else
            {
                Install.SetValue(AtStart, @"C:\Program Files\SystemFolder\ToolFolder\Toolname.exe", RegistryValueKind.String);
            }
        }
```

the code above does run without incident. But, the value is never implemented in the registry under the "Run" subkey. I have also tried to make the change using simply "Registry.SetValue(...)" as you can see above. Any help in regards to this issue would be GREATLY appreciated. If any other information is needed please let me know I will list all of the important things I can think of below

Basic Info:

1. Program is built as a console application
2. app.manifest is set to "requireAdministrator"
3. "using Microsoft.Win32" is present
4. the Target Framework is .Net 4.5
5. used on both win 7 and win 10 with the same results

Comment: Do you have x86 or AnyCPU as your target application? In x86 on a 64bit system you could experience the registry redirection situation. Check under WoW6432Note\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion

Comment: well, now i just feel stupid. I was able to find it in the WOW6432node set. I appreciate you pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @steve comment. 
To enable both 32-bit and 64-bit application access 
 certain  section of registry in a uniform fashion, WOW64 emulator provides a feature called registry re-direction. Primarily it maintains separate logical view of the registry key which is mapped to physical locations under Wow6432Node.
Not all registry keys are affected, you can find the affected keys here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396